# I am using IAR embended workbench software for STM32F407 how to setup for first use. I am trying but they show error

Tags: embedded, iar, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4

I am using IAR embended workbench software for STM32F407 how to setup for first use.  I ama trying but they shoe error.

Fatal Error[Lc002]: could not open file "C:\Program Files\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 9.2\arm\f\EWARM\iar_project.icf"   D:\Software files\IAR MICROPROCESSOR\IAR_First_Project\EWARM\Debug\Exe\iar_project.out.rsp  1

Please tell me how to fix this

Answer (score 1):

This is the IAR linker (`ilinkarm.exe`) telling you it cannot find the linker configuration file(`*.icf`) which is supplied via the `--config 《path-to\script.icf》` option.

The linker configurations included in the installation for ST can be found at `...\arm\config\linker\ST\*.icf`. They should work in general when, in the IDE, you create a project from scratch and select the desired target device in the project options.

Projects generated with ST's [STM32CubeMX](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubemx.html), come with target-specific linker configurations for the selected board: one for running it from FLASH and another for running it from RAM. The greatest advantage of using STM32CubeMX with IAR is that the entire project for the STM32F407 can be generated from scratch in the IAR format and provide means to initialize all the board'speripherals to their defaults. This is the least effort path I know for ST devices.

If you already have a project with a custom linker configuration, you can check the **override** option in the **Project**/ **Options**/**Linker**/**Config** tab.